# Schedule regular task without extending TimerTask?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, timer, runnable

How can I run instances of this class repeatedly in separate threads and given intervals?
(As you have noticed I am using Java 2 EE).

```
public class Gate extends AbsDBObject<Gate> implements Runnable{
  public void Run(){
    //Something
  }
}
```

I have done this before by `Gate` class extending the `TimerTask` class and using `Timer`:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
Gate gates = Gate.fetchOne();
timer.schedule(gate, 0, 1000);
```

But in this case I can't extend any other class. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) then you just execute `Runnable` objects, rather than `TimerTask` objects.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = 
    new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize);
Gate gate = Gate.fetchOne();
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(gate, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

That saves the need to extend.

Comment: can you explain the use of it a bit?

Comment: and also is there any way that i can stop it? i want to add a start stop link so i can control the service

Comment: @dave Take a look at the `ScheduledFuture` object returned from the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method.

Comment: executorService.shutdown()

Comment: @dave That's another alternative, although that will cancel *all* tasks in the executor service. Also, please note that typically the `shutdown()` or `cancel()` options will not interrupt a running task, unless that tasks can respond to thread interruption.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    final Gate gates = Gate.fetchOne();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            gates.run();
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: thnx for reply , what do you think about duncan jones's solution?

Comment: it's 100% better, but you asked about TimerTask :)